# How to use BSF within GQLAlchemy?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know how to use [BSF in Cypher](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/built-in-graph-algorithms#breadth-first-search) but I can't find anything on using BSF within GQLAlchemy. I've found [BreadthFirstSearch Objects](https://memgraph.github.io/gqlalchemy/reference/gqlalchemy/graph_algorithms/integrated_algorithms/) but I'm lacking some example. If you've used it, can you share part of the code with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at code from [test example](https://here%27s%20a%20test%20example%20for%20bfs%20https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy/blob/main/tests/query_builders/test_memgraph_query_builder.py#L207). I think that it should be a good starting point.

```
def test_bfs():
    bfs_alg = BreadthFirstSearch()

    query_builder = (
        QueryBuilder()
        .match()
        .node(labels="City", name="Zagreb")
        .to(relationship_type="Road", algorithm=bfs_alg)
        .node(labels="City", name="Paris")
        .return_()
    )
    expected_query = " MATCH (:City {name: 'Zagreb'})-[:Road *BFS]->(:City {name: 'Paris'}) RETURN * "

    with patch.object(Memgraph, "execute_and_fetch", return_value=None) as mock:
        query_builder.execute()

    mock.assert_called_with(expected_query)
```